# Calculate impulse response of a dynamic system

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems, signal-processing

I am given an exercise where I need to find the impulse response of the system
$$
y_n = 1.02(y_{n-1} + x_n).
$$

I have looked online but haven't been able to find an example with a system with memory.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Index $y_n$ usually indicates discrete sequences, are $x_n,y_n$ sequences then? What is $x_n$?

Comment: yn is a discrete sequence that represents balance at the end of each month and xn is the amount of money that we deposit each month ( 9000, 1000, -9000, -1000 ) in a given order

Comment: not sure what [impulse reponse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) means in this context. You have some values for $x_n$ and you want to spike one of the $x_k$ values and are asking for what the impact will be?

Comment: >  When a system is "shocked" by a delta function, it produces an output known as its   >  impulse response. For an LTI system, the impulse response completely determines   >  the output of the system given any arbitrary input. The output can be found using     >  discrete time convolution.

Comment: I need a function h(n) that instead of x(n) has a δ(n) function or something, haven't really understand

Answer (score 1):

Seeing this difference equation suggests using the Z-transform. This is because the transform of $x_{n-n_0}$ is $X(z)z^{-n_0}$, where $X(z)$ is the Z-transform of $x_n$.

You want to find the sequence $h_n$ such that $y_n=x_n \ast h_n$. In the Z domain we have that $Y(z)=X(z)H(z)$.

In the Z domain, you have the difference equation
$$Y(z)=1.02(Y(z)z^{-1}+X(Z)) \Longrightarrow H(z)=\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}=\frac{1.02}{1-1.02z^{-1}}$$

You can take a look at the [list of properties and common transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) and see that the antitransform of the latter gives

$$h_n=\begin{cases}1.02^{n+1}&\text{if }n\geq 0 \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\,.$$